# Permission denied in Minikube Docker Script

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes, minikube

I am new to Minikube and Docker. I have a setup of Minikube with three pods of apache spark.
One spark master and two spark worker. My docker file for spark master is as below,

```
# base image
FROM openjdk:11

# define spark and hadoop versions
ENV SPARK_VERSION=3.2.0
ENV HADOOP_VERSION=3.3.1

# download and install hadoop
RUN mkdir -p /opt && \
    cd /opt && \
    curl http://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}.tar.gz | \
        tar -zx hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}/lib/native && \
    ln -s hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION} hadoop && \
    echo Hadoop ${HADOOP_VERSION} native libraries installed in /opt/hadoop/lib/native

# download and install spark
RUN mkdir -p /opt && \
    cd /opt && \
    curl http://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz | \
        tar -zx && \
    ln -s spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop2.7 spark && \
    echo Spark ${SPARK_VERSION} installed in /opt

# add scripts and update spark default config
ADD common.sh spark-master spark-worker /
ADD spark-defaults.conf /opt/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
ENV PATH $PATH:/opt/spark/bin
```

When I deploy the pods I got an error,

```
Events:

  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message

  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------

  Warning  Failed     25m (x5 over 26m)     kubelet            Error: failed to start container "spark-master": Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/spark-master": permission denied: unknown
```

The contents of the script spark-master,

```
#!/bin/bash

. /common.sh

echo "$(hostname -i) spark-master" >> /etc/hosts

/opt/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip spark-master --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
```

Please help to solve this issue.
My Docker Version is:
Docker version 20.10.18, build b40c2f6

Comment: You can an error with kubectl apply deployment.yaml?

Comment: What does  minikube service list show?

Comment: Following services are running, kubernetes, spark-master, kube-dns, dashboard-metrics-scraper, kubernetes-dashboard

Comment: Kubectl describe service spark-master.

Comment: Name:              spark-master
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          component=spark-master
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.107.201.253
IPs:               10.107.201.253
Port:              webui  8080/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         
Port:              spark  7077/TCP
TargetPort:        7077/TCP
Endpoints:         
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

Comment: any way to isolate which line is causing the error? or reducing the code but still produce the error?

Answer (score 1):

In the Dockerfile I have commented out the following line

```
#ADD common.sh spark-master spark-worker /
```

Replaced the line with the below lines which resolved the permission error

```
COPY common.sh spark-master spark-worker  /
RUN chmod +x /common.sh /spark-master /spark-worker
```

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the script spark-master are as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

. /common.sh

echo "$(hostname -i) spark-master" >> /etc/hosts

/opt/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip spark-master --p spark-master-ui-port >> /var/log/spark-master.log 2>&1
```

Comment: I have updated the script spark-master with your changes, Rebuilded Docker image and deployed. I still get the same error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).